# Very basic AutoLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, autolayout

In a `View Controller` I have two `UILabels`.

I'm trying to start to understand the `AutoLayout` feature, but I'm finding tutorials using `storyboards`, complex layouts, `scrollViews` and other components that are absolutely more complex of what I'm trying to achieve and understand.

This is my very basic setup:

[image]

What I simply want - to start to dive in the subject - is:

- have the distance between the two `labels` preserved when testing it on 3.5' and 4' screens
- have the bottom and top margin of both the `labels` to be proportionally preserved when testing it on 3.5' and 4' screens. EDIT: please consider that the desired position it's not the exact center

I have tried to add constraints via the "Pin" option, but with no success at all. Maybe I should put them inside another view to act as a container?

This is a very easy question, but right now this AutoLayout feature is really confusing me. And maybe this can be a good starting point to understand what right now looks to me to be designed by a crazy scientist :)

Comment: I have been voted down for saying this in the past but think about watching the WWDC 2012 and WWDC 2013 videos on the topic. If you are a beginner to auto layout they will walk you through how it works conceptually, how to use it (both in code and in IB), common problems and how to trouble shoot issues.  Watching the videos will save you vast amounts of time.

Answer (score 2):

Put both UILabels in a containerView, and align containerView vertically center.

Comment: thank you for you suggestion, but what if it the desired position it's not the exact center?

Comment: If you don't want to vertically center, you have to set fixed y constraint for your upper label. If you want the y constraint to be different for 3.5" and 4", then create IBOUTLET for y constraint in your class. Then set yourYConstraint.constant value to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

I would support @RoboticCat for the statement he made. But I would try to deliver what I learned from those videos.

For first requirement:
Ctrl+click on any of the label & drag n drop it on another label. Select "Vertical spacing" option from the popup. this will full fill your first requirement.

For second one:
Ctrl+click on top label & drag n drop it on view of viewController. select "Top space..." option from popup.

repeat previous step between bottom label & view. This time select "Bottom space.. " option from popup.

Now navigate to Size Inspector of each label. There you can find the constraints just created. Click them to perform Edit.

Decrease priority of top & bottom constraints to 500 from concerned labels. This will solve your issue.

Let me know if more info needed.. :)

Comment: man, first of all thx for your detailed explanation, but unfortunately when switching screen size on the simulator the labels are still moving in the wrong way. Looks like it's applying a fixed amount of space for the top margin, for example. Should the constraints be presented in red? Right now they are red...

Comment: well, to be more precise, they actually don't move. I'm using a xib designed for 4' inch screen, and when visualising it in 3.5' screen looks like everything it's in the same position without any change

Comment: So... Is it working?? & constraints are not supposed to be in red colour.. You have to adjust the frame based on constraints.. :)